# How to create a dynamic matplotlib plot on a cartopy map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm creating a program that maps the journey of a ship from a dataset with latitude and longitude values. I am having a problem with a "dynamically updating" part.

I'm doing it all in Jupyter (python), and sadly I can't share my dataset. I have tried doing a regular dynamic matplotlib plot as per various guides online but it hasn't really worked. The one I put most time into trying was a line with xdata and ydata that updates every 0.1s, but this does not account for the fact that all my plots need to have transform=ccrs.Geodetic applied.

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=[20,10])#create figure with matplotlib
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1,projection=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo())#add a subplot using the cartopy SouthPolarStereo
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05, top=0.95,left=0.04, right=0.95, wspace=0.02)#adjust size
ax1.set_extent([-180,180,-180,-55],ccrs.PlateCarree())#show only below 55S lat
ax1.gridlines()
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
ax1.coastlines()
#adding some features to the map
#plt.plot("LONVAL","LATVAL",color="green",marker="o",transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
xdata=[]
ydata=[]
#empty x and y data
line,=ax1.plot(xdata,ydata,"r-")#line

for vals in latlong.itertuples():#latlong is a dataframe from my dataset with julian day, latitude and longitude
    jday,lat,lon=vals[1],vals[2],vals[3]
    xdata.append(lon)
    ydata.append(lat)
#append the x and y data with the lat and lon for that iteration
    line.set_xdata(xdata)
    line.set_ydata(ydata)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(1e-17)
    time.sleep(0.1)
#set x and y data and draw it. supposedly.
    #plt.plot(lon,lat,color="green",marker="o",transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
    #print(lat,lon)
#the above two lines work but just make me a static image.
#    print(xdata,ydata)
plt.show()
```

Expected result is a slowly drawn line animation type thing but instead it doesn't work.

Comment: If you wonder why no answers, then please [edit] your Q and show us your imports, we could guess but it's time consuming and we won't.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Are you not able to show an animation in juypter, or is there a problem with cartopy?